# PHP Variable undefined for eval function

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, eval

I'm new to PHP and coding in general.
Currently I'm trying to make a Simple Calculator.
For this I have the two scripts calculator.php and array.php
My Idea is to store all the inputs the user gives in an array so I can calculate them using the eval() function. Because I need a string for this I converted the array using a foreach loop.
But when I try to use the variable outside the foreach loop I get the following errors:

Notice: Array to string conversion on line 17
Array
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting '(' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dashboard/array.php(22) : eval()'d code on line 1

What can I do to fix this problem?

**array.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!is_array($_SESSION)) {
    $_SESSION['persistentValues'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
    $_SESSION['persistentValues'][] = $_POST['button'];
}



foreach ($_SESSION as $value) {
    echo $value;
}


if (isset($_POST["result"])) {
  $p = eval($value.";");
  echo $p;
}

?>
```

**calculator.php**

```
<?php

include ('./array.php');

?>


<div style="padding-left:40px">
        <h2> PHP Calculator</h2>
        <form method="post" action="">

            Enter value: <input type="text" name="value"> <br> <br>
            <div style="padding-left: 105px">
                <input type="submit" value="9" name="button">
                <input type="submit" value="8" name="button">
                <input type="submit" value="7" name="button">
                <input type="submit" value="+" name="button">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="6" name="button">
                <input type="submit" value="5" name="button">
                <input type="submit" value="4" name="button">
                <input type="submit" value="-" name="button" style="padding-left: 9px">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="3" name="button">
                <input type="submit" value="2" name="button">
                <input type="submit" value="1" name="button">
                <input type="submit" value="/" name="button" style="padding-left: 9px">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="0" name="button" style="padding-left:33px">
                <input type="submit" value="." name="button" style="padding-right:9px">
                <input type="submit" value="x" name="button" style="padding-left: 7px">
                <br>
            </div>
            <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Calculate" name="result">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you want `foreach ($_SESSION['persistentValues'] as $value)`

Comment: And `if (!is_array($_SESSION))` should also be `if (!is_array($_SESSION['persistentValues']))`

Comment: @Barmar when I use this the array gets displayed but I get the errors
Notice: Undefined index: persistentValues
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Notice: Undefined variable: value

Comment: @Barmar this fixed the Errors. When I load the page now I can input my numbers but when I click calculate theres still no output from the eval function.

Answer (score 2):

You're repeatedly confusing the whole `$_SESSION` variable with `$_SESSION['persistentValues']`. The latter is where you're holding the buttons as you submit them.

The value of `$value` is an array because you're looping over `$_SESSION` to set it, and the value of the session variable is an array. The argument to `eval()` is a string, and when you convert an array to a string it becomes the string `Array`, which isn't an expression that can be evaluated.

You can use `implode()` to concatenate all the elements of an array into a string. So if the session array contains `['9', '3', '+', '8']` it will set `$value` to `'93+8'`, which you can then pass to `eval()`.

The argument to `eval()` needs to be a statement. So you should put the `echo` command in the argument.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!is_array($_SESSION['persistentValues'])) {
    $_SESSION['persistentValues'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
    $_SESSION['persistentValues'][] = $_POST['button'];
}

$value = implode('', $_SESSION['persistentValues']);
echo $value;

if (isset($_POST["result"])) {
  eval("echo $value;");
}
?>
```

Comment: after typing in a calculation and pressing the result button I get the following errors:

Notice: Undefined index: persistenValues in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dashboard/array.php on line 13

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dashboard/array.php on line 13

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dashboard/array.php(17) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: Typo: `persistenValues` should be `persistentValues`